# jQuery complex hide show submenu

Tags: jquery, hide, show, submenu

I can't figure out a proper way to accomplish all the logic needed. The submenus needs to be outside of its menu link root, because of layout purposes. The logic needed is:

**When the submenu should OPEN:**

1. in a **touch device** when the user **tap** on link
2. in a **pointer decide** when the user **hover** on link
3. When the menu is opened, the link and the sub-menu must get the "active" class.

**When the submenu should CLOSE:**

1. When the "Close" button is clicked (its located inside submenu)
2. When another menu is open, the first menu should close
3. In a **touch** device, When you click anywhere outside the submenu
4. In a **pointer** device, when the mouse leaves the submenu area

---

EDITED: THIS IS THE FINAL CODE WORKING 100%
after @SilverSurfer awnser and some ajusts

---

```js
$(".sub-menu").hide()

$("a.close-bt").click(function(){
    $(this).closest(".sub-menu").hide()
    $(this).closest(".sub-menu").removeClass("active")
    $(this).closest(document).find("a.menu-item").removeClass("active")
});

$(document).on('click mouseover', "ul.menu > a", function () {
    $("ul.menu > a").removeClass("active")
    $(".sub-menu").hide()
    var target = "."+$(this).attr("id")
    $(target).addClass("active")
    $(this).addClass("active")
    $(target).show()
});
$(".sub-menu").mouseleave(function() {
    $(this).hide()
    $(this).removeClass("active")
    $(this).closest(document).find("a.menu-item").removeClass("active")
});
```

```css
// FUNCTIONAL STYLES

.menu {
 z-index: 2;
}
.menu a {
}
.sub-menu {
 //visibility: hidden;
 //visibility: show;
}
.close-bt {
 
}


// VISUAL STYLES, PLZ IGNORE
.menu {
}
.menu a {
 margin-right: 30px;
 background: green;
 display: inline-block;
 padding: 20px;
 color: white;
}
.menu a.active {
 background: red;
}
.sub-menu {
 width: 100px;
 height: 100px;
 background: lightblue;
 border: 2px solid black;
 z-index: 1;
 position: relative;
}
.sub-menu.active {
 visibility: show;
 background: blue;
}
.close-bt {
 background: red;
 color: white;
 padding: 10px;
 position: absolute;
 right: 10px;
 bottom: 10px;
}
ul { margin: 0; left: 0; padding: 0; }


.container  { position: absolute; top: 50px; left: 0; } 
.item1 { position: absolute; top: 10px; left: 0; }
.item2 { position: absolute; top: 10px; left: 110px; }
.item3 { position: absolute; top: 10px; left: 220px; }
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<ul class="menu">
 <a class="menu-item" id="item1" href="javascript:void(0);">Link 1</a>
 <a class="menu-item" id="item2" href="javascript:void(0);">Link 2</a>
 <a class="menu-item" id="item3" href="javascript:void(0);">Link 3</a>
</ul>


<div class="container">
 <div class="sub-menu item1">
    <a class="close-bt" href="javascript:void(0);">Close</a>
  Sub-menu 1
 </div>
 <div class="sub-menu item2">
    <a class="close-bt" href="javascript:void(0);">Close</a>
  Sub-menu 2
 </div>
 <div class="sub-menu item3">
    <a class="close-bt" href="javascript:void(0);">Close</a>
  Sub-menu 2
 </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Check my answer please

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Is this what are you looking for?

```js
$(".sub-menu").hide()

$("a.close-bt").click(function(){
    $(this).closest(".sub-menu").hide()
    $(this).closest(".sub-menu").removeClass("active")
    $(this).closest(document).find("ul").removeClass("active")
});

$(document).on('click mouseover', "ul > a", function () {
    $(".sub-menu").hide()
    var target = "."+$(this).attr("id")
    $(target).addClass("active")
    $(this).closest("ul.menu").addClass("active")
    $(target).show()
});
```

```css
// FUNCTIONAL STYLES

.menu {
 z-index: 2;
}
.menu a {
}
.sub-menu {
 //visibility: hidden;
 //visibility: show;
}
.close-bt {
 
}


// VISUAL STYLES, PLZ IGNORE
.menu {
}
.menu a {
 margin-right: 30px;
 background: green;
 display: inline-block;
 padding: 20px;
 color: white;
}
.menu a.active {
 background: red;
}
.sub-menu {
 width: 100px;
 height: 100px;
 background: lightblue;
 border: 2px solid black;
 z-index: 1;
 position: relative;
}
.sub-menu.active {
 visibility: show;
 background: blue;
}
.close-bt {
 background: red;
 color: white;
 padding: 10px;
 position: absolute;
 right: 10px;
 bottom: 10px;
}
ul { margin: 0; left: 0; padding: 0; }


.container  { position: absolute; top: 50px; left: 0; } 
.item1 { position: absolute; top: 10px; left: 0; }
.item2 { position: absolute; top: 10px; left: 110px; }
.item3 { position: absolute; top: 10px; left: 220px; }
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<ul class="menu">
 <a id="item1" href="javascript:void(0);">Link 1</a>
 <a id="item2" href="javascript:void(0);">Link 2</a>
 <a id="item3" href="javascript:void(0);">Link 3</a>
</ul>


<div class="container">
 <div class="sub-menu item1">
    <a class="close-bt" href="javascript:void(0);">Close</a>
  Sub-menu 1
 </div>
 <div class="sub-menu item2">
    <a class="close-bt" href="javascript:void(0);">Close</a>
  Sub-menu 2
 </div>
 <div class="sub-menu item3">
    <a class="close-bt" href="javascript:void(0);">Close</a>
  Sub-menu 2
 </div>
</div>
```

Comment: wow! beautiful code :)
its missing only one thing: hide the menu when, in pointer devices, mouse leaves the sub-menu...